# Total Allowed Variables

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005 and have a stored procedure (not written by me) that I now have to maintain. Its an important query and I want to make some changes to make it easier to maintain without totally rewritting the whole thing. Just exploring some options, so...

How many variables can I have in a stored procedure (is there a limit)?

```
DECLARE @MyVariable int
```

Comment: I don't know that there's a hard limit. But if you're asking about a limit, there is probably a problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, No kidding...Like I said, don't want to have to rewrite the whole thing, just make it a little easier to maintain. I am sure that I wouldn't be anywhere close to a limit, but I don't like to just assume. So I just want to do a little research. I am thinking I am just going to end up rewritting this thing in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191132%28SQL.105%29.aspx), there is a limit of 2100 parameters that can be passed to a stored proc, so I would assume you could do at least that many variables.

**Edit:**

Per article:

> The maximum number of local variables in a stored procedure is limited only by available memory.

Comment: Great...this article has the answer (I edited your answer with the exat text)...thanks.